# Access edit record button on continuous subform

Tags: ms-access

I have a form in Access and there is a subform in it as in the screenshot (light purple is main form, dark blue is subform header).

Subform is a continuous form. I have added 2 images to the subform and want to edit a record based on the row ID.

[image: Form with subform]

OnClick event of the image, I tried to add a message box to show the values of

```
Me.ID
```

or

```
Me.CurrentRecord
```

but they both always show the same value for all the rows.

The edit image click will open an Unbound form so in the OpenArgs of the Form I need the Id that is selected and will populate the Unbound Edit form based on the selected ID.

How can I get the pressed image Id of the record in the Contious subform ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While clicking on the detail section background does select the record where you clicked, clicking on an image **doesn't**.
So just clicking on the image won't change the record selection, and you always see the data of the previously selected record.

While developing / debugging, you should turn on **RecordSelectors** in the subform, to see what is going on.

You need an actual button to achieve both in one click: select record + do action.

Solution 1: use a normal button with your image as button image.

Solution 2: put a **transparent** button in front of the image.

In both cases, move your code to the button click event.

Comment: Yes, I think I'll delete, as somehow I missed the suggestion to use a button with image.  No worries